# First decomposition theorem of fuzzy set

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, fuzzy-set

I read if standard union in fuzzy set have definition:

Union of two fuzzy sets $\tilde{A}$ and $\tilde{B}$ in universe $X$ denoted $\tilde{A}\cup\tilde{B}$ is fuzzy set in universe $X$ with membership function
$$
\mu_{\tilde{A}\cup\tilde{B}}(x)=max\{\mu_\tilde{A}(x),\mu_\tilde{B}(x)\}
$$
But in prove of first decomposition theorem, I found this

$$
\mu_{\bigcup_{\alpha\in[0,1]}\tilde{A}_\alpha}(x)=\sup_{\alpha\in[0,1]}\mu_{\tilde{A}_\alpha}(x)\\
\mu_{\bigcup_{\alpha\in[0,1]}\tilde{A}_\alpha}(x)=\max\{\sup_{\alpha\in[0,a]}\mu_{\tilde{A}_\alpha}(x),\sup_{\alpha\in(a,1]}\mu_{\tilde{A}_\alpha}(x)\}
$$

**So why first using supremum to union of fuzzy set and then using maximum again?**

If X is set with partial ordering relations, I know if $S\subseteq X$
$$
\sup S = \max S
$$
But in the theorem just say $X$ is universe.

Note:

1. $\tilde{A}$ is fuzzy set in universe $X$.
2. $A_\alpha$ is strong $\alpha$-cut from $\tilde{A}$.
3. $\tilde{A}_\alpha$ is fuzzy set in universe $X$ with membership function.
   $$
   \mu_{\tilde{A}_\alpha}(x)=
   \begin{cases}
   \alpha & \mbox{if $x\in A_\alpha$}\\
   0 & \mbox{if $x \notin A_\alpha$}
   \end{cases}
   $$